# Slow hotkey response in GNOME 3.12

Tags: linux, gnome, arch-linux, hotkeys, gnu

I run Arch, and I recently grabbed the 3.12 upgrade for GNOME. I've had F12 bound to `terminator` for a while, since I often have to summon new terminals.

Ever since the upgrade, using a hotkey for a command can take up to 30 seconds, when it used to be instant. Launching the program graphically is still instant.

I've tried using different hotkeys, and I've tried binding the hotkeys to different commands, and they all behave this way.

Comment: I just reported a bug here:https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729101

Answer (score 4):

From the [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729101) filed by [xgdgsc](https://superuser.com/questions/742914/slow-hotkey-response-in-gnome-3-12#comment963562_742914), this slow response to GNOME shortcuts appears to be caused by `gnome-keyring-daemon`. In particular, having multiple instances of the daemon appears to cause shortcut execution to pause while attempting to communicate with the daemon until it times out. You can use the following command to check if you have multiple instances of the daemon running:

```sh
pgrep gnome-keyring --list-full
```

On CentOS 7 with GNOME 3.14.2, I was able to work around this by killing both processes:

```sh
killall gnome-keyring-daemon
```

`gnome-keyring-daemon` automatically restarted with only one instance when I next used a GNOME keyboard shortcut, and the shortcut executed instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and facing this bug since 3 or 4 months ago after an big `dist-upgrade`. By these workaround suggested by the previous answer  I've created this script to run as soon as the login session start:

```
#!/bin/bash

# # # # # # Description
# From the bug filed by xgdgsc, this slow response to GNOME shortcuts appears to be caused by gnome-keyring-daemon. 
# In particular, having multiple instances of the daemon appears to cause shortcut execution to pause while attempting to
# communicate with the daemon until it times out.
# source: https://superuser.com/questions/742914/slow-hotkey-response-in-gnome-3-12

#
# Requisites user with sudo rights
#
echo "workaround to bug gnome bug 729101"
if [ $(pgrep gnome-keyring --list-full | wc -l) -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "killing all gnome-keyring processes"
    sudo killall gnome-keyring-daemon
    [ $? -gt 0  ] && echo "error $? " && exit 1
    echo "applied successfully"    
else
    echo "It's ok!"    
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Ubuntu 16.04 after installing `flatpak` which installed `dbus-user-session` as a dependency.  I removed `flatpak` and it's installed apps.  Then,

`sudo apt-get remove --purge dbus-user-session`

I also changed my passwords on my user via `passwd` and on my login keyring via `seahorse` or Passwords & Keys app in ubuntu.

After rebooting I am no longer experiencing slow hotkey response and other issues.

Check out this bug report for more context:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825